# WPF DataTemplate previewmouseleftbuttonup not working

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, mouseup

I have Listbox with ListItemTemplate. There are two commands I want attach with each list item.

1) PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown :  I use this even when for drag and drop functionality. user press button event gets fired and I came to know how many items user has selected for dragging.

2) PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp: I want to use this when user release mouse from list item. (But issue is this even never gets fired. It seems like 1st event taking control of both.

Here is my code. Pls help.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListItemTemplate">
    <Grid Margin="0" Width="58" Height="58" x:Name="OuterGrid">         
        <Border x:Name="OuterBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ContentToGreyedOutBrush}" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0" Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                                        ClipToBounds="True" CornerRadius="0">
            <Border x:Name="InnerBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0" Background="Transparent" CornerRadius="0">
                <Grid>
                    <Image Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding Path=FileName,Converter={StaticResource FileNameImageConverter}}"
                                    Width="50" Height="50">
                    </Image>
                    <ToggleButton x:Name="zoomButton" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                           VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" Background="Transparent" Cursor="Hand" Template="{StaticResource ZoomTemplate}" Width="20" Height="20" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    </ToggleButton>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Border>
        <ac:CommandBehaviorCollection.Behaviors>
            <ac:BehaviorBinding Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"  Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}},Path=DataContext.DragItemSelectedCommand}" 
                                CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"/> 

    <ac:BehaviorBinding Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"  Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}},Path=DataContext.MouseUPCommand}" 
                                CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"/>
        </ac:CommandBehaviorCollection.Behaviors>
</Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: The tunnling part of the preview is handled in the listbox before it reaches the listboxitem  ,Why Preview and not regular ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to do dragging of the item to a different location outside the original bounds. In this case the up event would be firing on the new control over which the mouse is located when it is released, not the control that you started dragging. To make this work you need to make sure to capture the mouse when starting a drag operation.